# ERRNO: 2 TEXT: define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, smarty

ERRNO: 2
TEXT: define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

class Link
{
public static function Build($link)
{
$base = 'http://' . getenv('SERVER_NAME');

```
    // If HTTP_SERVER_PORT is defined and different than default
        if(define('HTTP_SERVER_PORT') && HTTP_SERVER_PORT != '80')
        {
            // Append server port
            $base .= ':' . HTTP_SERVER_PORT;
        }

        $link = $base . VIRTUAL_LOCATION .$link;

        //Escape html
        return htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    public static function ToDepartment($departmentId)
    {
        $link = 'index.php?DepartmentId=' . $departmentId;

        return self::Build($link);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in condition. You can use defined() function in place of define(), because define() function use for declare constant which is expect  two parameter, one is for constant name and another is value of that constant.While defined is return true if we have declared that variable.
Here is the Updated Syntax :

```
 if(defined('HTTP_SERVER_PORT') && HTTP_SERVER_PORT != '80')
    {
        // Append server port
        $base .= ':' . HTTP_SERVER_PORT;
    }
```

Comment: I'd call it a typo more than a syntax error...